# Zapier Mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, zapier

We are using a Mysql database setup to be accessible remotely with SSL/TLS and attempting to connect it to Zapier. 
Tutorial on how the database is setup [Here](https://alephnull.uk/configure-mysql-mariadb-ssl-tls-debian-ubuntu). I have verified that the Database is accessible from a number of IP addresses, and that permissions are set as loosely as possible.

> mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
>
> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '[User]'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD < secret > REQUIRE SSL
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `[User]`.* TO '[Database]'@'%'

We can connect the database to Zapier and it passes the initial connection test, but when attempting to select dropdown options in the following set up options this error is thrown and the dropdown list is empty.

> We're having trouble loading 'Table' data...
>
> internal returned (401) Unauthorized and said "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/srv/app/sql_zero/frontend.py", line 151, in get_tables response_obj = database_service.get_tables(params, auth=auth) File "/srv/app/sql_zero/database_service.py", line 125, in get_tables with connection(self.connect(auth, params['engine'])) as engine: File "/srv/app/sql_zero/database_service.py", line 282, in connect return available_enginesdatabase.connect(auth) File "/srv/app/sql_zero/engines.py", line 60, in connect engine.execute('SET NAMES utf8;') File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1990, in execute connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2039, in contextual_connect self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None), File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2078, in _wrap_pool_connect e, dialect, self) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection exc_info File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect return fn() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 376, in connect return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 713, in _checkout fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout rec = pool._do_get() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1060, in _do_get self._dec_overflow() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in **exit** compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1057, in _do_get return self._create_connection() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection return _ConnectionRecord(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 449, in **init** self.connection = self.**connect() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 607, in __connect connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 97, in connect return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 385, in connect return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init**.py", line 90, in Connect return Connection(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in **init** self.connect() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 928, in connect self._request_authentication() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1148, in _request_authentication auth_packet = self._read_packet() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1010, in _read_packet packet.check_error() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception raise errorclass(errno, errval) OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user '[user]'@'ec2-54-86-9-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)") "

I have checked the guidance [here on empty dropdown lists](https://zapier.com/help/troubleshooting-your-zaps/#dropdown-choices-are-empty) but nothing worked. If we ignore the message and manually enter a table and a simple query

> SELECT * FROM `learner`

It throws the following error at 'Test this Step'.

> Bargle. We hit an error fetching a row. :-( Error:
>   internal returned (401) Unauthorized and said "Traceback (most recent call last).

Any help figuring out what is going on here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try ruling out it being a Zapier issue by testing the connection from another MySQL client (like [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else in future, the solution is to set up a client certificate for Zapier to authenticate with the MySQL server. Zapier support confirmed that it's not possible to authenticate using a username and password when `REQUIRE SSL` is enabled, even though this isn't stated in their documentation.